# Projecting the In- class demo screen

Tags: coding-style, classroom-infrastructure

I want to do an in-class demo for students.
I am wondering if there's a way I can project my code editor for students to see, and still have a document with written code (like a cheat sheet) which only I can see.

Please suggest how this might this be done

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se]! Your question sounds interesting. You could improve it by adding information about context. i.e. what class is it? high-school, university etc.
Also, if you could mention what resources are at your disposal (is there a teacher computer in the classroom etc.) people could answer much more useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a standard projector, here are two ways that I do this:

1. A printout.  Nothing like going old-school and having physical paper in front of you.  Your students can't see what you've got written down. As a side benefit, you can comment in notes about things to say.  Want to code in some errors and then fix them to make a point? It's easy to document a process this way.
2. Set your laptop to use dual-monitors, and use the primary as your laptop screen. And the secondary as your projector screen.  A side benefit here is that the text doesn't get as difficult to read on the projected screen.  A challenge is potentially having to turn your head when typing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a notebook that's mirrored to a ceiling mounted projector. And I use multiple desktops on Windows 10 to switch between applications if I'm doing more than one thing.  I usually go from memory, but have a printed copy of what I'm demoing to fall back on just in case.

Also have Adobe Connect running so that students can mirror my screen to their screen. Computers are setup so students are facing either a side or back wall so being able to mirror keeps the from having to bend their necks.

I record a screen cast and upload the video so they can come back to it later like notes.